# c array to python

Tags: python, c, ctypes

I need to handle a big array of data from C program to python instance (Django) using shared library (.so). 
Is it possible to return them through ctypes ?

For example:

```
import ctypes
a = ctypes.CDLL('foo.so')
b = a.collect()
latitude  = b.latitude
longitude = b.longitude
```

and a C:

```
main()
{
    /* steps to get the data */
    return <kind of struct or smth else>;
}
```

I am the newbie so is there a ways of delivery of such kind of data ?

Answer (score 1):

One option is to return the values via pointer parameters:

```
// c 
void collect(int* outLatitude, int* outLongitude) {
    *outLatitude = 10;
    *outLongitude = 20;
}
```

and

```
# python
x = ctypes.c_int()
y = ctypes.c_int()
library.collect(ctypes.byref(x), ctypes.byref(y))
print x.value, y.value
```

---

If you need more than that, you could return a structure:

```
// c
typedef struct  {
    int latitude, longitude;
} Location;

Location collect();
```

and

```
# python
class Location(ctypes.Structure):
    _fields_ = [('latitude', ctypes.c_int), ('longitude', ctypes.c_int)]

library.collect.restype = Location
loc = library.collect()
print loc.latitude, loc.longitude
```

---

BTW: You have mentioned Django; I'd be careful with concurrency here. Note that your C library may be called from different threads.

Comment: BTW other solutions: a) See projects like [ctypesgen](http://code.google.com/p/ctypesgen/) to read headers and write these Python definitions for you. b) Use boost::python or SWIG to compile the C/C++ code into a real Python module. You can also read my article: [5 ways to use Python with native code.](http://kos.gd/2013/01/5-ways-to-use-python-with-native-code/)

Comment: there are no problems with c_int. Now i can't figure out how to use c_char_p and pass strings to python. Can you give a sample ?

Comment: See [Fundamental data types](http://docs.python.org/2/library/ctypes.html#fundamental-data-types) in the docs, I can't describe that better. (For simple read-only passing, you can just pass a Python string to the function, assuming it has `argtypes` set correctly - ctypes will autoconvert)

Comment: i meant a pointer to string from C to python and get it as x.value for example

Comment: Oh, in this way. Set the function's restype to `c_char_p` and it should return Python strings.